# Select a specific element from HTML data in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stored the results of `$.get()` into a variable called `questionsdata`. The data is basically a bunch of divs with unique ids. I wish to find just one `div` using an id. I can kind of understand that this wouldn't work but I don't know what would.

```
$(questionsdata).find("#593");
```

Example data in the variable:

```
<div id="591">Stuff</div>
<div id="592">Stuff</div>
<div id="593">Stuff</div>
<div id="594">Stuff</div>
```

Comment: What is `questionsdata` ?

Comment: you basically want to find `value` in `string`? i belive the `questionsdata` contain `html` tag that you show as example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse HTML stored in a text variable with jquery quite easily - it doesn't need to be added to the DOM.

As #593 is at the top level, `.find` will not find as it searches children.  Instead you could use `.filter` if it will always be at the top level, or wrap in another `<div>` - either at the source or via jquery:

```js
var data = '<div id="591">Stuff1</div><div id="592">Stuff2</div><div id="593">Stuff3</div><div id="594">Stuff4</div>';

console.log($(data).find("#593").length)

// Use .filter
console.log($(data).filter("#593").text())

// Or wrap with a div
console.log($("<div>").html(data).find("#593").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed not realising that find searched children of the selected was my problem - filter worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var questionsdata = '<div id="x"><div id="a591">Stuff1</div><div id="b592">Stuff2</div><div id="c593">Stuff3</div><div id="d594">Stuff4</div></div>'
 

console.log($('#b592',questionsdata ).html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wasn't quite sure what to do when two answers are right. I chose @freedomm-m's because it addressed the particular mistake I made (using find instead of filter) but I can see your answer being just as correct.

Comment: @Daniel you can upvote helpful answers, even if you accept a different one (just upvote the accepted one as well :) )

Comment: Unfortunately I can't adjust the HTML output that much. While numbers in id's was bad in HTML4, in 5 it's ok (but not in CSS). I saw the $("something",something) being used in other places - what is going on there? Can you direct me to where this type of selection is explained? Couldn't find it on the Selectors page in jquery.

Comment: @daniel your id namings are ok, while I inpecting my code I named like that. `$("something",something)` may not be common but useful as well while `filter()` and `find()` is ok

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript

```
var data='<div id=591>Stuff</div>
<div id="592">Stuff</div>
<div id="593">Stuff</div>
<div id="594">Stuff</div>';
var $data = $(data).appendTo('#container");
var my_div=$("#container").find("#593");
```

Your HTML

```
< div id="container"></div>
```

Your CSS

```
#container{display:none;}
```

Comment: There's no need to incur the delay (however minor in *this* case) of adding the html to the DOM to find a specific element.  In fact, this may cause errors if your existing html contains nodes with the same IDs.   Finally, consider using a code-snippet.

Comment: Ok but if we deal with ajax required data so each time it will be different , so add it to a container is not a bad idea , about the node which will include the same IDs I think structuring the code is the thing we have to take care about.